# software that will use keyword to voice activate an app

Tags: voice-recognition

I am looking for a lite software or script that will activate an application when a keyword is triggered.

I want to use it with `google2ubuntu`, for example I would set a keyword (ubuntu) and it would activate `google2ubuntu` and the rest is history.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) in recently implmeented keyword spotting mode. Checkout pocketsphinx from subversion trunk and try pocketsphinx_kws tool for keyword spotting. You can run it something like this:

```
 pocketsphinx_kws -kws "oh mighty computer" -infile file.wav
```

You can read from microphone too.

Comment: Could not compile it :( but hell with it

Comment: If you have troubles to compile you are welcome to ask on CMUSphinx forum